# No Activity found to handle Intent when using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

In my app I have a custom auto download and install APK it works like this

```
  // auto register for the complete download
     activity.registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));



 // Download the file through DownloadManager
 String destination = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
    String fileName = "myfile.apk";
    destination += fileName;
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new  DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(apkUrl));
    request.setDescription("description");
    request.setTitle("title");
    request.setDestinationUri(uri);
    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

          Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          // BEFORE working doing this
          //install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
          //install.setDataAndType(uri,
          //    manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));

          // Using file provider it doesnt work
          Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AutoUpdate.this,
              "com.myapp", file);
                install.setDataAndType(apkUri,manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
          activity.startActivity(install);
          activity.unregisterReceiver(this);

      }
    };
```

Android manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myapp"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

Provider_path (Sorry for some reason so cuts the path tag)

> external-path name="myfolder" path="."/>

When the file finished to download the onComplete is called but the activiy doesn't start:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=content://com.myapp/myfolder/myfile.apk
>   typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x4000000 }

When using the normal file:// it does work

Is there something I'm missing when using the file provider? Does the activity doesn't start because the file is not found ?
Do I need extra permission ? (at the moment I have INTERNET, READ and WRITE on external storage)

Comment: `Does the activity doesn't start because the file is not found `. The message is that the activity is not found.

Comment: Note that "if" I substitute the mime type by "*/*" it does open the app selection but when i chose the "file manager" it just opens it and stays at the root. That's why I'm wondering by using the FileProvider the file is not actually found ?

Comment: where have you declared "file" variable?

Comment: Why are you using "com.myapp" as authorities in your manifest but later you use "com.myapp" by hard-coding it when calling getUriForFile()? If your package name is com.company_name.application_name I think the authority must be "company_name", you don't have to add the ".com", are you sure you have a well formatted name for your package?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The package installer only supports `content` schemes starting on Android 7.0. Prior to that — and despite documentation to the contrary — the package installer only supports `file` schemes.

You will need to set the `Uri` on your `Intent` differently based on whether you are running on Android 7.0+ or not, such as by branching on `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`.

Answer (score 8):

Commonware is right,
For those looking for the code:

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

       downloadButton.setEnabled(true);
       downloadButton.setText("Terminado");
       progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

       if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
            Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            Uri apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                     self,
                     self.getApplicationContext()
                     .getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
            install.setDataAndType(apkURI,
                    manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
            install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(install);
       } else{
            String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
            String fileName = "surveyevent.apk";
            destination += fileName;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

            Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            install.setDataAndType(uri,
                    manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
            startActivity(install);
       }
       unregisterReceiver(this);
       finish();
  }
};
```

Comment: @lacas final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

Comment: what is downloadId?

Comment: Why you append ".provider" to the package name? An Android package extension is always ".apk" and if you rename the apk file like this the system would never know about the type of the download. Have you ever tried to make that code run and work?

Answer (score 0):

Your provider is not found because

```
 android:enabled="true"
```

is missing in your manifest.

But then it will not work either reading the other answer of CW.